# Using Fabric.js in a Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, fabricjs, google-chrome-app

So, I'm building a simple video editor. I'm using Fabric.js `<script src="/js/fabric.js"></script>` to manipulate the canvas on which I'm doing the editing.

I've left out the Serialization and Parser models of it but it still uses eval for something which throws an error:

`Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".`

`fabric.Canvas(String id)` still works but shape objects don't (e.g. `new fabric.Rect();` throws an `Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Circle is not a constructor`)

This is my first Chrome app and I don't really understand what's happening. If anyone could help me figure out how to use Fabric in this environment that would be most excellent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your using a custom build of fabric? I've heard it sometimes leaves important stuff out. can you use the whole library and see if that works?

Comment: Known bug: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that Fabric is not `'unsafe-eval'` CSP-compliant is a [known issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1621).

As such, the only way to use it in an app or an extension is to sandbox it: perform all operations in a frame loaded as sandbox, and pass data both ways with `postMessage`.

See the documentation article ["Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely."](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval)